# jQuery - Passing a variable into .not() within a foreach loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop

When I use the following code without a variable it works fine:

```
$( "div#bottomSelector div button" ).not( "#black" ).addClass('greyed');
```

However when to replace the id's with a variable and loop for each one it doesn't. It applies the `greyed` class to all of the buttons within the selector.

```
variants.split(",").forEach(function(each) {
  var id = '#' + each
  console.log ( id );
    $( "div#bottomSelector div button" ).not( id ).addClass('greyed');
});
```

The console log for this returns the following:

```
#bamboo
#black
#white
```

The markup is:

```
<div id="bottomSelector">
    <div><button id="bamboo">Bamboo</button></div>
    <div><button id="black">Black</button></div>
    <div><button id="walnut">Walnut</button></div>
    <div><button id="gold">Gold</button></div>
    <div><button id="white">White</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#bamboo` and `#white` are `not(#black)`. `#black` is `not(#bamboo)`. See the issue now?

Comment: @CollinD I'm not sure I understand. There are some buttons with ID's that shouldn't be affected like green, pink or walnut.

Comment: @CollinD ahhh wait I get it. My mind is pickled.

Comment: To offer a little bit of clarification, DeMorgan's law says what you're doing `!A || !B || !C === !(A && B && C)` When what you really want is `!A && !B && !C` which is `!(A || B || C)` I'll post this as an answer since it helped.

Comment: @CollinD Yeh right so what I really want is .not( #bamboo, #black, #white )

Comment: @CollinD wait no it isn't that will try to find elements with all three ids?

Comment: Can you please provide the markup that would be really helpful

Comment: @Gorg I've added an answer with code that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each iteration of your loop, 2/3 of your buttons qualify for getting the `greyed` class.

This is because `#black` and `#white` match `not('#bamboo')`. Next time around, `#bamboo` matches `not('#black')` and all three of your buttons now have the `greyed` class added.

What you should do instead is make sure that each element has NONE of the ID's. You can do this pretty easily by just chaining calls to `$().not`

This is due to a logical equivalence that can be a little bit unintitive if you don't write it out.

```
!A || !B || !C === !(A && B && C)
```

When what you want is

```
!A && !B && !C === !(A || B || C)
```

The code you want is something more like this:

```
var buttons = $( "div#bottomSelector div button" );
variants.split(",").forEach(function(each) {
  var id = '#' + each
  buttons = $(buttons).not( id );
});
$(buttons).addClass('greyed');
```

Comment: Collin, this is a great answer, thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I really understand why this wasn't working now.